# Is there a way to place enum type in variable for later casting?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I'm written a function that given an object's name and a value, returns the text names of the bits.  These bit names are defined in an various enums.  Here is the essence of my function.

```
string BitName(string object_name, long bit_value) {

  string bit_name="";    

  switch(object_name) {
    case "STATUS_WORD" :
      bit_name = ((eStatusWord)bit_value).ToString();
      break;
    case "TRAJ_STATUS" :
      bit_name = ((eTrajectoryStatus)bit_value).ToString();
      break;
  }
  return bit_name;
}
```

This simple approach worked, but now there are more actions that will create a lot of replicated code.

At minimum I'd like to place the enum type into a variable and use that for casting.   Something like this:

```
   Type my_type = eStatusWord;        
   bit_name = ((my_type)bit_value).ToString();
   // addition actions that are type dependent
```

If its possible then a Dictionary could replace the switch statement.

Comment: With `Dictionary<string, Type>` you may, for example, use `Convert.ChangeType()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enum.ToObject` allows you to dynamically reconstruct an enum by knowing the type.

From there, you can use a `Dictionary<string, Type` to map the string to the enum type, and reconstruct the value:

```
bit_name = Enum.ToObject(dictionary[object_name], bit_value).ToString();
```

To populate the dictionary, use `typeof`:

```
dictionary.Add("STATUS_WORD", typeof(eStatusWord));
```